# Transcribe Welsh Audio Recording using Azure

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to use Azure services to transcribe an audio file (in the Welsh language)?  Looking at the following page it appears that this is not available.

please help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#speech-translation

Comment: "Looking at the following page it appears that this is not available" what do you mean by that? Welsh is on the list

Comment: It says: The source language must always be from the Speech-to-text language table -  so I have an audio file of someone speaking in Welsh, I need to be able to convert it to text and possibly to English thereafter. Does that make sense?

Comment: oh sorry yes, I just saw the "text" languages. You are right, Welsh is not allowed as a speech input based on the array